# Show post published live

Tags: posts

I want to show my new post published live in page without refresh. something like breaking news in blog websites.

How can i do this?
anybody knows?

Comment: You could use an ajax request with a setTimeOut

Comment: @Jim-miraidev could you send me ex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function for your ajax request, and set a timeout so it repeats. You will also need to send the ids of the current news articles being displayed so you can exclude them from your new WP_Query in your PHP

UPDATED - This now uses a data attribute to create an array of post ids to exclude off the next ajax request.

live.php

```
<div class="latest-news">
      <?php 
        $current_posts_ids = array();
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
          <div class="posts">
            <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
              <?php array_push($current_posts_ids, get_the_ID() );?>
              <article data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID()?>">
                <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_excerpt() ?><p>
              </article>
            <?php endwhile ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif ?>
 </div>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

      var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";   
      var dataArray =  <?php echo json_encode($current_posts_ids) ?>;

      function getMyPosts() {

            data = { action: "update_news", data: dataArray};
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                // reset array
                dataArray = [];
                // append the new news posts                
                $('.latest-news .posts').append(response);
                // create new array of ids to exclude
                $('article').each(function(){
                    dataArray.push($(this).data('id'));  
                }); 
                // repeat function after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getMyPosts();
                }, 5000)
            });

     }
     //run the function first time
     getMyPosts();   

});
</script>
```

function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_news', 'update_news' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_news', 'update_news');
function update_news() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post__not_in' => $data,
    );
    $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if($my_posts->have_posts()) :
    while($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post();          
        echo "<article data-id='".get_the_ID()."'>";
        echo "<h2>" . get_the_title() . "</h2>";
        echo "<p>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p>";
        echo "</article>";
    endwhile;
    endif;

 wp_die();

}
```

Comment: just put it on my page?

Comment: Put the JS in a JavaScript file that is included on the page you are showing the posts. The php then goes into your function.php file. The 'action': 'update_news' in the ajax direct to the function  'wp_ajax_update_news'.

Comment: i put it but nothing show still

Comment: i put my code on second answer

Comment: can you update the question instead of the answer please and i will update the answer

Comment: could you do this things for me?

Comment: thanks a lot, i have a little problem yet that is the posts are showing but my first post is repeating ...

Comment: http://ahanalat.co/live/

Comment: something wrong in js code, page doesn't load correctly

Comment: problem fixed??

Comment: I will look into this now, can you please remove your other answers

Comment: thank you so much my friend, how can i add a sound when new post publish?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. First you need to please mark the correct answer to your question above, so that people with the same issues can find the solution. Then if you create a new question the community will be glad to help.

Comment: i have a problem still with this code
when new post publish i have no css style on it until i refresh the page

Comment: I've just looked at your site, first thing you need to do is fix your google map JavaScript error.

Comment: you just need to append the response inside the <div class="posts"> tags. Code updated.Do you know how to use the developer tools? As this would have flagged this issue, if not i would defiantly recommend researching.

Comment: i apologize you, but i didn't know js

Comment: how can i order this results?
i do this thing with php code but it doesn't work.
when new post published it's get down under other posts.

Comment: best thing to do is start a new question and show the code you have tried. Someone will help.

Answer (score 0):

my live.php page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";

    function getMyPosts() {
            // get the current ids of the post on that page using a
            var $current_posts = [1,2,3] //example of id array

            var data = {
                'action': 'update_news',
                'posts': 1,
                'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                // append the new news posts
                $('.latest-news').append(response);
                // repeat function after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getMyPosts();
                }, 5000)
            });
     }
     //run the function first time
     getMyPosts();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and my function code:

```
function live_post() {

  global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

  $data = $_POST['data'];
  $current_posts = $_POST['posts'];
  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post', // add post type
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => '-1',
      'post__not_in' => array( $current_posts )
  );
  //Query the posts
  $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) :
      ?>
      <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
          <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
          <?php the_excerpt() ?>
      <?php endwhile ?>
      <?php
  endif;
  wp_die();
  }


add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_news', 'live_post' );
```

Comment: first you need to add you original loop to get the post on load

Comment: could you do this things for me?